# EMR HBASE - "java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist" seen using Scan from read replica. Scan from replica-0 is successful

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, hbase, amazon-emr

I am using single 20-node EMR HBASE (HDFS) cluster. I have created a table with region replication enabled (REGION_REPLICATION=>'3') and column family (REPLICATION_SCOPE=>'1'). There are about a 1000 regions in the table and the table data size is ~1TB. The following custom configurations have been set on the cluster.

## **Configuration**

```
hdfs-site , `dfs.replication` , 3   
hbase , `hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles` , 100
hbase , `hbase.ipc.server.max.callqueue.size` , 2147483648  
hbase , `hbase.region.replica.replication.enabled` , true   
hbase , `hbase.regionserver.handler.count` , 160    
hbase , `hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.get` , 10  
hbase , `hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.multiget` , 10 
hbase , `hbase.ipc.client.allowsInterrupt` , true   
hbase , `hbase.region.replica.replication.memstore.enabled` , true  
hbase , `hbase.region.replica.wait.for.primary.flush` , false   
hbase , `hbase.regionserver.storefile.refresh.period` , 30000   
hbase , `hbase.replication` , true
```

I'm trying to figure out the cause of this error and the fix for this issue in order to ensure that reads from replicas are successful. Please let me know if you need any more information to help with your analysis.
Thank you.

I am trying to execute a SCAN on the table. Here are my observations:

1. when executing SCAN on the master replica (replica-0), It's running fine and returning the results.
2. When executing SCAN on the read replicas (replica-1, replica-2), it's returning a FileNotFound Exception.

`scan 'test', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE', REGION_REPLICA_ID=>1 , LIMIT=>10}`

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hbase/data/default/test/<dummy-value-for-stackoverflow>/cf/<dummy-value-for-stackoverflow>
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getBlockLocations(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1099)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3316)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.refetchLocations(DFSInputStream.java:1042)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchBlockByteRange(DFSInputStream.java:1147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.pread(DFSInputStream.java:1511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.util.BlockIOUtils.preadWithExtra(BlockIOUtils.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readAtOffset(HFileBlock.java:1450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockDataInternal(HFileBlock.java:1673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockData(HFileBlock.java:1484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl.readBlock(HFileReaderImpl.java:1314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl.readBlock(HFileReaderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl$HFileScannerImpl.readNextDataBlock(HFileReaderImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl$HFileScannerImpl.isNextBlock(HFileReaderImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl$HFileScannerImpl.positionForNextBlock(HFileReaderImpl.java:870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl$HFileScannerImpl._next(HFileReaderImpl.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderImpl$HFileScannerImpl.next(HFileReaderImpl.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.HalfStoreFileReader$1.next(HalfStoreFileReader.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.next(StoreFileScanner.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.next(StoreScanner.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MobStoreScanner.next(MobStoreScanner.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.KeyValueHeap.next(KeyValueHeap.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.populateResult(HRegion.java:7026)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.nextInternal(HRegion.java:7192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.nextRaw(HRegion.java:6962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3618)
    ... 5 more
```

Additional Observations:

1. from the HBASE UI, I see that for any given region, while replica-0 size is in 10's of GBs, replica-1 and replica-2 is 0GB. After a few hours, some of the replicas seemed to have replicated, but most of them are still at 0GB.
2. From the HDFS Name Node UI, the storage capacity is not an issue (~70% available).